# Get vuex store state after dispatching an action

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating a chat application in **Laravel 6** + **Vue** + **Vuex**. I want make a call to vuex store and get a state after a dispatch actions is complete and then I want to do some processing on that state in my vue component.

In **ChatWindow** component

```
mounted: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('setContacts').then(() => {
        console.log('dispatch called')
        // I want to call the getter here and set one of the data property
    });
}
```

**action.js**

```
setContacts: (context) => {
    axios.post('/users').then(response => {
        let users = response.data;
        // consoled for testing
        console.log(users);
        context.commit('setContacts', users);
    });
}
```

**mutators.js**

```
setContacts: (state, users) => {
    state.contacts = users;
},
```

Please see the screenshot below. The **then** method of **dispatch** is running before **setContacts** in **action.js**.

[image: image of console.logs]

I need to call the **getter** after completing **dispatch** action. (which will effectively set the contacts state). Then, I want to get the contacts through **getContacts** getter like this.

**getters.js**

```
getContacts: (state) => {
    return state.contacts;
}
```

I also tried calling computed property in **then** in **mounted** and it didn't work. Also, shouldn't 'dispatch called' in mounted run after console.log of **setContacts** in **action.js** as it is in then method? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could wrap axios call inside another promise.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   axios.post('/users')
     .then(response => {
        let users = response.data;
        // consoled for testing
        console.log(users);
        context.commit('setContacts', users);
        resolve('Success')
     })
     .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
     })

})
```

And then

```
this.$store.dispatch('setContacts')
   .then(() => {
       console.log('dispatch called')
       console.log('getter ', this.$store.getters.contacts)
   });
```

Let me know what happens. It was working for a small demo that I tried.

Comment: @S.Farooq Awesome mate